# Can I make TCP Keep-Alive symmetric?

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, nginx, tcp

I have a server (nginx on Ubuntu) which has `listen 80 so_keepalive=4m::;`. I have a windows client which I set the TCP Keep-Alive timeout with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220(v=vs.85).aspx . I set the server timeout to 4 minutes and the client timeout to 5 minutes. What I notice now, capturing the data between them with Wireshark is that after 4 minutes the server sends the TCP Keep-Alive and then one minute later (at 5 minutes from the start) the client sends its own TCP Keep-Alive. Why isn't the timer reset upon receipt of the servers Keep-Alive packet? Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The TCP Keep-Alives is kind of a hack that was added later to the protocol.

There is the relevant [RFC-1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101) paragraph about the question you have:

> **4.2.3.6  TCP Keep-Alives**
>
> [...snip...]
>
> To confirm that an idle connection is still active, these implementations send a probe segment designed to elicit a response from the peer TCP.  Such a segment generally contains `SEG.SEQ = SND.NXT-1` and may or may not contain one garbage octet of data.  Note that on a quiet connection `SND.NXT = RCV.NXT`, so that this `SEG.SEQ` will be outside the window.  Therefore, the probe causes the receiver to return an acknowledgment segment, confirming that the connection is still live.  If the peer has dropped the connection due to a network partition or a crash, it will respond with a `RST` instead of an acknowledgment segment.
>
> [...snip...]

In other words, a TCP Keep-Alive segment uses an old sequence number (`SND.NXT-1`) and expects a valid reply from it. There isn't really anything else that distinguish that segment from a normal segment. The TCP stack on the other end does not need to implement anything special to know that a Keep-Alive segment was sent. As long as the protocol was properly implemented, with or without the Keep-Alive feature, it will work *transparently*.

As mentioned in the RFC, there are cases where a TCP implementation will not answer such a request properly unless it includes at least one *octet* of data. I do not know which ones (Microsoft?)...

Further, the documentation says that only the server side should make use of the Keep-Alive feature. For sure, if you know that a server has the Keep-Alive turned on, then there is no need for you to have it in your client.